# "org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class..." when deploying to glassfish server

Tags: java, spring, maven, exception, glassfish

I get this error message when I'm deploying/publishing to Glassfish.
I am using Glassfish 4.0, Eclipse Kepler, Maven, Spring Security and PostGreSQL database.

Earlier this day everything worked just fine, I could publish without any errors. Then hoping to solve some other problem, where a jsp-page couldn't find a ManagedBean class, although I successfully worked with managed beans before, I rightclicked on my project and did "build project" and then rightclick on project->Maven->Update Project, which I read somewhere else.
After that the error appeared.

I guess there is something wrong with the classpath, because I noticed some java-classes are missing in the build-folder which can be seen in the project explorer in eclipse.
Unfortunatly this is my first JavaEE/Maven project so I don't know how to solve this problem.

relevant part from Stacktrace (appears several times):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [util.MyAuthenticationHandler] for bean with name 'myAuthenticationHandler' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.MyAuthenticationHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:354) [spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:82) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362) [web-core.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743) [web-glue.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898) [web-core.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691) [web-glue.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041) [web-core.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024) [web-core.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747) [web-core.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278) [web-glue.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924) [web-glue.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139) [web-glue.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122) [internal-api.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291) [internal-api.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352) [internal-api.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219) [kernel.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491) [deployment-admin.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523) [kernel.jar:na]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_17]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356) [na:1.7.0_17]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534) [kernel.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224) [kernel.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246) [kernel.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.MyAuthenticationHandler
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761) ~[war-util.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611) ~[war-util.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:392) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

The class MyAuthenticationHandler DOES exist in package "util" in src-folder.
As I said before, everything worked before and I didn't change anything in my code.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
">

    <!-- begin Spring Security config -->
    <sec:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <!-- Don't SSL encrypt static resources -->
    <!--  <sec:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/> -->

    <sec:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/faces/loginerror.jsp">

        <!-- On Glassfish, dev ports are 8080 and 8181, whereas on
        production its 80 and 443 -->
        <sec:port-mappings>
            <sec:port-mapping http="8080" https="8181"/>
        </sec:port-mappings>

        <sec:intercept-url 
            pattern="/faces/admin/**" 
            access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
        <sec:intercept-url 
            pattern="/faces/users/**" 
            access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
        <sec:intercept-url 
            pattern="/**" 
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>

        <!-- Use O/S provided login window
        <http-basic />
        -->
        <!-- Use custom form for login -->
        <sec:form-login 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            login-page="/faces/login.jsp" 
            authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/faces/loginerror.jsp"/>

        <sec:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" 
                    invalidate-session="true" 
                    logout-success-url="/faces/index.jsp" />

    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:password-encoder ref="encoderBean">
                <sec:salt-source user-property="username"/>
            </sec:password-encoder>
            <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                users-by-username-query=
                "select username, password, enabled from expuser where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                "select username, authority from expuser where username=?" /> 

            <!-- if not using a database for accounts, hard-code them here
           <sec:user-service>
               <sec:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_MEMBER" />
               <sec:user name="member" password="member" authorities="ROLE_MEMBER" />
           </sec:user-service>
            -->
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="myAuthenticationHandler" class="util.MyAuthenticationHandler" />
    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

    <bean id="encoderBean" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="512" />
        <property name="iterations" value="1024"/>
    </bean>


    <!-- Server managed connection pool accessed via JNDI -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/Datasource"/>

    <!-- (Optional) Automatically receives and logs AuthenticationEvent messages -->
    <bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener"/>

</beans>
```

MyAuthenticationHandler.java:

```
package util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

public class MyAuthenticationHandler extends
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String userTargetUrl = "/faces/users/indexUser.jsp";
        String adminTargetUrl = "/faces/admin/indexAdmin.jsp";
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if(roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")){
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, adminTargetUrl);
        }else if(roles.contains("ROLE_USER")){
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, userTargetUrl);
        }else{
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using Maven->Update Project means that project properties updating according your *pom.xml* file. Check your *Java Build Path* and *Deployment Assembly*.

Comment: Could you please be more specific what exactly I should check there? Which setting are important or necessary in the Deployment Assembly?

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/maven/troubleshooting-maven-dependency-libraries-not-deployed-in-eclipse-ide/